# program that reads simple data declarations and responds with the amount of memory that would be allocated to that variable

Tags: c, string, parsing, memory

I have written a program that reads simple data declarations and responds with the amount of memory that would be allocated to that variable.

Each input line should consist of - A type name, which must be one of the following: char, int, short, long, float, or double. - One or more individual declaration specifications separated by commas. - A semicolon marking the end of line.

In my code I also add a use of file (see below).

**I would like to ask youhow can I use sizeof instead the way I coded the size of data types to be allocated. I also would like to ask you whether my use in file is right.**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void bytesPerValue(char str[], char* filename) ;
int theSizeOf(char *str);
 int strToNumber(char *str);

void main()
{
     char str[50];

     gets(str);

     bytesPerValue(str,"input.txt");

}

void bytesPerValue(char str[], char* filename) 
{
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int temp = 1;
        int size;
        char* tempChar = (char*)malloc((strlen(str))*sizeof(tempChar));
        FILE *f=fopen(filename,"w");
        if (f==NULL)
            exit(1);
        while (str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*') //checking the type of the variables//
        {
                tempChar[j] = str[i];
                i++;
                j++;   
        }
        tempChar[j] = '\0';
        size = theSizeOf(tempChar);
        j = 0;
        i++;
        while (str[i] != ';')
        {

                if (isalpha(str[i]) || str[i]=='_') // for  variables and arrays//
                {
                        while (str[i] != ',' && str[i] != ';') //runs until ', ' or '; ' //
                        {
                                if (str[i]==' ')
                                {
                                        while (str[i]==' ')
                                                i++;
                                }

                                if (str[i] == '[') //checks if it is array//
                                {
                                        printf("%c", str[i]);
                                        i++;
                                        while (str[i] != ']')
                                        {
                                                tempChar[j] = str[i]; //copies the value in the string//
                                                i++;
                                                j++;
                                        }

                                        tempChar[j] = '\0';
                                        temp = strToNumber(tempChar); //converting to number in order to valuate the bytes//
                                }
                                printf("%c", str[i]);
                                i++;

                                if (isspace(str[i]))
                                {
                                        while (isspace(str[i]))
                                                i++;
                                }
                        }
                        fprintf(f," requires %d bytes \n", temp*(sizeof(temp)));
                }


                if (str[i] == '*') //for pointers//
                {
                        while (str[i] != ',' && str[i] != ';')
                        {
                                printf("%c", str[i]);
                                i++;
                                if (str[i]==' ')
                                {
                                        while (str[i]==' ')
                                                i++;
                                }
                        }
                        fprintf(f," requires %d bytes \n", 4);
                }
                if (str[i] != ';')
                        i++;
        }

 fclose(f);
}

int theSizeOf(char* str) // checking the size of the variable
{
        if (strcmp(str, "int")==0 || strcmp(str, "long")==0 || strcmp(str, "float")==0)
                return 4;
        else if (strcmp(str, "char")==0)
                return 1;
        else if (strcmp(str, "double")==0)
                return 8;
        else if (strcmp(str, "short")==0)
                return 2;
        else 
            return 0;
}


int strToNumber(char* str) //converting the string to number//
{
        int temp=1;
        int num=0;
        int t;
        int i;
        int length = strlen(str);
        for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                t = str[i] - '0';
                num += t * temp;
                temp *= 10;
        }
        return num;
}
```

Comment: For code optimisation and improvement you might try code review : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Starting at the "top", `void main()` can be improved with the modern definition `int main(void)`. Looking further down I suggest the use of `size_t` and not `int` where the size is returned by a function. Moreover `int strToNumber` suggests that a negative number may be read, but the code makes no attempt at that. Yet more: `return 8;` should be `return sizeof(double)` and so on with the other types.

Comment: ... you have hard coded the size of the data types with assumptions, and ignored that types `int` and `long` and `short` are defined by the C standard to have a *minimum* size, whereas `float` and `double` are implementation defined. However, you got right that `char` is of size 1, by definition.

Comment: A possible error: function strToNumber (str): what will happen if your number is greater than an int?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this type of question is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I tried to use sizeof, but for some reason I got a wrong output when I ran my code.

Comment: @barmar,  but I would like to ask how can I use sizeof instead the way I coded the size of data types to be allocated.

Comment: You can change `return 4` to `return sizeof(int)`, `return 1` to `return sizeof(char)`, etc.

Comment: @NoaRoth You could also use a lookup table instead of a bunch of `if` statements. This is the kind of advice that you'll get if you post on CR.

Comment: `while (str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*')` is same as `while (str[i]!=' ')` .  This line of code is suspicious.  Without a `' '` in `str[]`, infinite loop and array bounds error.

Comment: "I tried to use sizeof, but for some reason I got a wrong output" `printf("%zu", ... );`

Comment: They didnt teach me such a thing %zu , I must say..

Comment: For your interest you might like to try `printf("%zu", sizeof('a'));`

Answer (score 1):

> how can I use sizeof instead the way I coded the size of data types to be allocated?

```
size_t theSizeOf(const char* str) {
  if (strcmp(str, "char"  )==0) return sizeof(char);
  if (strcmp(str, "short" )==0) return sizeof(short);
  if (strcmp(str, "int"   )==0) return sizeof(int);
  if (strcmp(str, "long"  )==0) return sizeof(long);
  if (strcmp(str, "float" )==0) return sizeof(float);
  if (strcmp(str, "double")==0) return sizeof(double);
  return 0;
}
```

Or use an array

```
size_t theSizeOf(const char* str) {
  const struct {
    const char *type;
    size_t size;
  } types[] =  {
     {"char", sizeof(char) },
     {"int", sizeof(int) },
     // Add others as needed.
     {"double", sizeof(double) },
  };
  for (size_t i=0; i< sizeof types /sizeof types[0]; i++) {
     if (strcmp(str, types[i].type)==0) return types[i].size;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

> I also would like to ask you whether my use in file is right.

Many issues such as

```
    // No need for cast
    // buffer allocation 1 too short
    // wrong sizeof argument
    char* tempChar = (char*)malloc((strlen(str))*sizeof(tempChar));
    // instead use
    char* tempChar = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    // potential infinite loop as code does not check for null character
    while (str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*') {
      ...

    // Does not handle negative numbers nor overflow of `temp`.
    strToNumber()
```

Comment: How souild I fix       while (str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*')  and       strToNumber()?

Comment: @NoaRoth Describe what you want the `while (str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*')` loop to do.

Comment: I want that loop to skip the spaces. what is wrong in it?

Comment: @NoaRoth So you want the loop to quit processing `str[]` when it first encounters a space?  Then use `while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i]!='\0')` so it quits when it finds a space or a _null character_.

Comment: @NoaRoth Your loop is wrong as it does not stop when the end of the string is detected.

Comment: @NoaRoth With C, if code does things it should not, the results are not certain.  It may "work well" for your select data  today but maybe not tomorrow or on other machines and other comilers.  See [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Found a little more complex to read but ultimately why you simply move the challenge to this entry a little simpler:

Entrance:
1 (10) ====> 10 bytes
5 (4) =====> 5x4 bytes
...
Int, double ...., what is their real size for computers?

Answer (score 0):

StrToNumber () must throw an error if the number overflows from an int.

This is the only way to make this program clear.

If it is a computer, you will not be able to address the memory if the number is greater than an int. In this circumstance, the amount of memory is not possible on this computer.

To process a larger memory, use a computer that can take a larger integer.

If your challenge is to program in C, this code is a bit confusing. If the challenge is to allocate a certain amount of memory, a better program will simply answer that question with yes or no.

Comment: As this is a C post, how do you should code "throw an error" using standard C?

Comment: In C, a realizable approach when "the number overflows" is to set `errno` rather than "throw an error".  This is the way used by the standard C library function `strtol()`.

Comment: The variable "errno" is usually set automatically. This is a global variable. Any other error replaces this value.

Comment: `errno` is not set automatically on `int` overflow.  Code must explicitly set it.  Standard C library `strtol()` does set it under various conditions.

Comment: @chux: Have you ever seen the implementation of strtol () or does it come from your imagination?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145735/discussion-between-user1587368-and-chux).