# Printing text from file to the screen

Tags: c, file

Suppose I put some text in a file, what is the quickest way to print it to the screen after I close the file?

For example, in the following function I use printf to put some text to a file. **I would like that text to be an output to the screen.**

```
void calcMemoryOfVariables(char str[], char* filename) 
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int temp = 1;
    int size;
    char* tempChar = (char*)malloc((strlen(str))*sizeof(tempChar));
    FILE *f=fopen(filename,"w");
    if (f==NULL)
        exit(1);

    while (str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*') //checking the type of the variable//
    {
        tempChar[j] = str[i];
        i++;
        j++;   
    }
    tempChar[j] = '\0';

    size = calcSize(tempChar);  //the size of that variavle in bytes//

    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (str[i] != ';')
    {

        if ((str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') || (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z')) // for  variables and arrays//
        {
            while (str[i] != ',' ) 
            {
                if (str[i]==' ')
                {
                    while (str[i]==' ')
                        i++;
                }

                if (str[i] == '[')      //checks if it is an array//
                {
                    printf("%c", str[i]);
                    i++;
                    while (str[i] != ']')
                    {
                        tempChar[j] = str[i]; //copies the value in the string//
                        i++;
                        j++;
                    }

                    tempChar[j] = '\0';
                    temp = strToInt(tempChar); //converting to int in order to valuate the bytes//
                }
                printf("%c", str[i]);
                i++;

                if (str[i]==' ')
                {
                    while (str[i]==' ')
                        i++;
                }
            }
            fprintf(f," requires %d bytes \n", temp*(sizeof(temp)));
        }


        if (str[i] == '*')           //for pointers//
        {
            while (str[i] != ',' && str[i] != ';')
            {
                printf("%c", str[i]);
                i++;
                if (str[i]==' ')
                {
                    while (str[i]==' ')
                        i++;
                }
            }
            fprintf(f," requires %d bytes \n", 4);
        }
        if (str[i] != ';')
            i++;
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: You might want to think about `(str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*')` for a moment.

Comment: what's wrong with it?

Comment: Try thinking about the condition logically.

Comment: `(str[i]!=' ' || str[i]=='*')` : Since `'*'` is not a `' '`, the right part is practically meaningless and the whole is the same as `str[i]!=' '`.

Comment: `while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp))fputs(buff, stdout);`

Comment: `while (str[i]==' ')
                        i++;` Such a loop seems to cause a buffer overrun if the input is incorrect.

Comment: It seems already the same point has already been pointed out in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315983/program-that-reads-simple-data-declarations-and-responds-with-the-amount-of-memo).

Answer (score -1):

You could use sprintf to write the text into an array.
This would allow you to write the text to a file and print it on the
screen:

```
char output[16];
FILE* fd = fopen("output.txt", "w"); 
sprintf(output, "%s", "Output Test\n");
printf("%s", output);
fwrite(output, 1, strlen(output), fd);
fclose(fd);
```

Comment: It would be better if you elaborate it with an example.